# Plot time on y-axis and time on x-axis in MS Chart

Tags: c#, mschart

I am new to MS Chart and graph world!!

My requirement is as follows

We have attendance Management System which logs in coming and out going time of employees.

My task is to create graph that will plot date on x axis and time on y-axis.

E.g. if an employee came at 9:00 AM in morning on 15th Sept 2012, then 15th Sept will show on x-axis and y value will be 9:00 AM.

So on selection of date range such a graph will be plotted.

I am getting value in datetime format from database

Please let me know how do i do it?

I am using C#.Net and MS Chart

Answer (score 0):

this is the simplest explanation I could come up with.Take a good look at it
[Chart Control in WinForms](http://www.dotnetperls.com/chart)

Let us know if it helps

Comment: i need to display x-axis both at the top and bottom of chart. that is i want duplicate x-axis.please let me know how can it be achieved??

Answer (score 0):

May be this example could ameliorate your problem.[Date Time Manipulation](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-parse)

Feel free to mark it as answer if it helps

Comment: Please edit and update a **single** answer instead of posting new answers to every comment.